# How can i paste picture onto another as layer ( so without PNG grid) using Python Pillow

Tags: python-imaging-library

Using Python Pillow I am trying to paste png picture (of a cartoon person on a non background greyish grid -standard for png files...i hope you know what i mean) as a top layer of another picture background.

I would like to paste it such that cartoon person fit nicely into my picture background and do not carry the background from original file (which is png grey grid).

In other words, when I paste a person which is a png file without background on my desired background I am left with a square picture of o person not as layer but as a whole picture on top of background.[not wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvBXZ.png) [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Urr.png) [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBa8v.png)[person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSYqN.png)

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

bkg = Image.open("background.png")
prsn=Image.open("person.png")

bkg.paste(prsn,(45,35))
bkg.load()
bkg.show()
bkg.save('resul.png')
```

Comment: Please show your code. Also, you'll need 3 images - a cartoon, a background, and some indication of the expected result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so nearly there, you just need to use a mask where you paste so you don't affect areas in the background under transparent parts of the person:

```
bkg.paste(prsn,(45,35),prsn)
```

Also, this line is unnecessary:

```
bkg.load()
```